# add new div and end div every 3 data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want the template is clear. every 3 div then added new div and close div. and looping my data.

I have trouble when data is looping then the template is corrupt...

Here is my query

```
<?php 
    $i = 1;
?>
<?php foreach ($produk as $i) : ?>
    <?php if ($i%3==0): ?>

        <div class="grid1_of_3">
            <a href="details.html">
                <img src="images/pic6.jpg" alt=""/>
                <h3>branded cargos<?= $i['harga'];?></h3>
                <div class="price">
                    <h4>$300<span>indulge</span></h4>
                </div>
                <span class="b_btm"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

    <?php else : ?>

        <div class="grids_of_3">
        <div class="grid1_of_3">
            <a href="details.html">
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt=""/>
                <h3>branded bags<?= $i['harga'];?></h3>
                <div class="price">
                    <h4>$300<span>indulge</span></h4>
                </div>
                <span class="b_btm"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>



    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>


    <div class="grids_of_3">

        <div class="grid1_of_3">
            <a href="details.html">
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt=""/>
                <h3>branded bags</h3>
                <div class="price">
                    <h4>$300<span>indulge</span></h4>
                </div>
                <span class="b_btm"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="grid1_of_3">
            <a href="details.html">
                <img src="images/pic5.jpg" alt=""/>
                <h3>ems women bag</h3>
                <div class="price">
                    <h4>$300<span>indulge</span></h4>
                </div>
                <span class="b_btm"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="grid1_of_3">
            <a href="details.html">
                <img src="images/pic6.jpg" alt=""/>
                <h3>branded cargos</h3>
                <div class="price">
                    <h4>$300<span>indulge</span></h4>
                </div>
                <span class="b_btm"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

i have template like above, every 3 of 
 then added  and close div

the simple is every 3 div class, then add 1 new div and close div

Comment: need to clear your question

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the index with the value in the foreach statement. If you have a numerically indexed array (starting with 0), you use:

```
foreach ($array as $index => $value)
```

and then check every third element with:

```
if (($index + 1) % 3 === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will give  you  your required Code

```
$produk = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
$length = sizeof($produk)

<div class="grids_of_3"> 
<?php foreach ($produk as $index => $i) { ?>

        <div class="grid1_of_3">
            <a href="details.html">
                <img src="images/pic6.jpg" alt=""/>
                <h3>branded cargos<?= $i['harga'];?> <?php echo $index ?></h3>
                <div class="price">
                    <h4>$300<span>indulge</span></h4>
                </div>
                <span class="b_btm"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php  if( ($index + 1) % 3 == 0  && ($index+1) != $length){ ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div><div class="grids_of_3">
       <?php  } else if(($index+1) == $length){ ?>
            </div>
       <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Result Code Will Be as Follow

```
<div class="grids_of_3">

        <div class="grid1_of_3">
            <a href="details.html">
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt=""/>
                <h3>branded bags</h3>
                <div class="price">
                    <h4>$300<span>indulge</span></h4>
                </div>
                <span class="b_btm"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="grid1_of_3">
            <a href="details.html">
                <img src="images/pic5.jpg" alt=""/>
                <h3>ems women bag</h3>
                <div class="price">
                    <h4>$300<span>indulge</span></h4>
                </div>
                <span class="b_btm"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="grid1_of_3">
            <a href="details.html">
                <img src="images/pic6.jpg" alt=""/>
                <h3>branded cargos</h3>
                <div class="price">
                    <h4>$300<span>indulge</span></h4>
                </div>
                <span class="b_btm"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```